# Incompatible types in java

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, incomplete-type

I am trying to take a `String` from a `JTextField` using `getText` and apply it to the method
`SearchString` but i am presented with the error **Incompatible Types** i cannot see anything wrong with this code however.

ActionListner code:

**String whatToSearch,result**

**JTextField searchfield**

**method SearchString**

EDIT: have changed to Public String, but i am now given a Missing Return Statement error at the line shown above

Comment: Certainly, the compiler tells you what where the `Incompatible Types` occur and which are those 2 types. Can you be more explicit on that error?

Comment: incompatible types
  required: java.lang.String
  found:    void

        in console i am presented with a mass of actionperformed errors but the above is the in code error

Comment: can you show searchString method and what does it return?

Comment: Your method SearchString does not return a value (`void`), but you are asigning it to your result-variable. Regarding to your error, result possibly is a String var, and thus you get the error, that you can't assign `void` to `java.land.String`

Comment: here is the error:  public `void` SearchString(String input) . You want to return `String` in order to be a compatible type.

Comment: Not fixing the Problem but I suggest to start the Method Name with a lower case letter to be conform with Naming conventions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compilation error is saying that you can't assign the result of `SearchString(whatToSearch)` to `result`.  This is because `SearchString` is declared to return NO result; that's what `void` means!

The fix is to change the signature to `public String SearchString(String input) ...` and change the body to return a String value at the appropriate point or points.

Comment: After changing to Public String i am now shown with a Missing return statement error, dont think i should need a return statement? :S

Comment: Yes you should.  If you want your method to return a String, the body has to say *which* string to return!

Comment: Sorted it now, was ridiculously simple!